# How do you assess for mode bias and scale effects when designing survey questionnaires?

Tags: survey, bias, hypothesis-testing

We typically educate clients on the potential bias of one mode over another (online versus paper surveys for example) and the bias a scale can have when designing questionnaires.  A client recently asks me how we could test for this bias and I am looking for ideas?

Comment: Sometimes there's no shortcut to reading the literature.  For example, many back issues of Public Opinion Quarterly deal with this topic. Probably so do many other sources, including the American Statistical Association's Survey Methods Section Newsletter.  But it's too broad a question for this forum, imo.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assess scale or mode effects in surveys you have to set up an experiment. Split your sample in two groups, and interview each group using a given mode. For such an experiment to be valid, you have to be able to control your environment as much as possible. At the end you have to be sure that possible differences in the outcomes can be attributed to the interview mode. This can be achieved if you assign the interview modes randomly. In the experiment, the choice of the mode should not depend on internal or external factors. Internal factors, are mainly the profiles of the interviewees and external factors are related to the environment the interviewees live in.

As @rolando2 has pointed out, there are papers on mode effects, and it could be worthwhile to have a look at that literature.

Comment: +1 -- randomization into the mode is a necessary component of such a comparison. Otherwise, there is no real telling from the observational data and one confounding on top of the other.

Comment: I disagree about randomizing the mode is necessary or appropriate - while it would be able to tell you specifically about the mode, it is likely impractical and not predictive of actual results, because the sample source is almost always specific to the mode. You could start with one sample source (e.g., phone numbers) and after recruitment, sort them into one mode or the other mode (finish the survey on phone, or direct online), but if that's not the methodology that will really be employed for an online survey, and it probably won't be, then the experiment will not predict real world results

Answer (score 0):

For testing, the best method would be to include both modes in one project and compare the results. This is commonly done when switching from  phone to online methodology, when sufficient funds are available.

You can also test sequentially, which is cheaper, but this always leaves the question of whether any differences are due to methodology or an actual change.